# spring-boot: Ensure that the submitted value is one of a given set of valid choices

Tags: spring-boot, validation

In PHP/Symfony framework, we can validate a request value if it's one of a set of values using Choice constraint as described in this link:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Choice.html

for example, I want to test if category_id is one of the following: [1,2,3,4].
is there any way to this validation in spring-boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my question, I had to create a function annotated with **@AssertTrue** and check if the value is allowed to be submitted from the allowedValues array
like this:

```
int[] allowedValues = {1,2,3,4};
@AssertTrue
public boolean isValidType() {
    return IntStream.of(allowedValues).anyMatch(x -> x == this.typeId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem lends itself to a simpler core java implementation. This is definitely better solved with `enum`, but if you'd rather use a validation library then hibernate validator is better for this case.

Example field declaration:

`@Range(min = 1, max = 4)
int category_id;`

https://hibernate.org/validator/

Comment: it's working, but what if I have values with a gap? ex [1,3,6]
or string values like: ['Apple','Banana'] ?